# Apple mail sending "Untitled attachment #####.htm" to outlook along with other attachments

Tags: mail.app, email

So I've got a coworker who uses apple mail. When he sends out attachments, they show up as the attachment as well as an "Untitled attachment #####.htm" file along with it (1 attachment becomes 2, 2 becomes 4, et al).

My boss has asked me to look into this because the Mac based coworker sends out several pdf's to clients (This happens on other files too though), and weird attachments may look like spam/viruses to the clients, something we're not too keen on.

Does anyone know why this is, and if its fixable through apple mail? I've done some research, but the jury seems pretty out on this on. I can say along with attachments, this coworker uses an html based signature, but if that breaks things, he can probably use an image based one.

Answer (score 5):

Do you see these strange attachments in some version of Outlook?

In my own testing it seems to be that if there is anything after an attachment then Outlook interprets it as another unnamed attachment and generates an ATT0001.txt file (I'm assuming different versions of Exchange or Outlook might result in different names for the attachments).

If you make sure that the attached PDF is the last thing in the email then Outlook seems to parse the emails okay.

About the `Insert attachments at End of Message` option on the Edit -> Attachments menu in Mail. By default if you drag an attachment onto a Mail message window it'll place the attachment wherever you drop the attachment. But if you select the `Insert attachments at End of Message` option, then when you try to attach a file Mail will automatically drop it at the end of the message no matter where you actually position the cursor as you drag the attachment over the window. However it won't prevent you subsequently typing text after the attachment, which results in the ATTxxxx.txt file.

Long story short, make sure the PDF attachment is at the very end of the email and Outlook should parse the email okay.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: We checked that one and it was already checked. We unchecked them to test (Just to be sure) and no effect.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear. Both were checked already? Or just one?

Comment: Both were checked already.

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix,
Use this extension for Mac Mail:

http://universalmailer.github.io/UniversalMailer/download.html

EDIT: Nazi mods edited my post. This is COMPLETELY free. The author accepts donations on the page.
<strike>It is available under the MIT license, you have to pay for the ad free version, but there are these [other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38320/how-to-set-a-default-font-for-outgoing-messages-in-mail-on-lion) benefits to using it.</strike>